# TensorFlow unstack with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, matrix, data-science

I am porting code from tensorflow to numpy and i have trouble with this line of code:

```
tensor_unstack = tf.unstack(some_tensor, axis=0)
```

The [tf.unstack](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unstack) method is used and i was unable to find a equivalent in numpy. So my question is how would a tf.unstack be implemented when using numpy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [star operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean) can be used to unstack a numpy array. Here is an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([4, 5, 6])
c = np.stack([a, b])
*d, = c
print(d)

c_ = tf.stack([a, b])
d_ = tf.unstack(c_)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(d_))
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above does not allow one to specify the split axis or the number of splits one wants to make.

Thankfully, a better solution is provided by inbuilt numpy functions. Look into [`numpy.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) and its specialized versions `numpy.hsplit`, `numpy.vsplit`, `numpy.dsplit` and `numpy.array_split`.

```
import numpy
a = numpy.arange(9).reshape(3,3)

# makes 3 equal splits along axis 0. equivalent to numpy.vsplit
print(numpy.split(a, 3, axis=0))

# 3 equal splits along axis 1. equivalent to numpy.hsplit
print(numpy.split(a, 3, axis=1))
```

Comment: this, however, will preserve the "unstacked" dimension: if `x.shape: (4, 2, 3)`, then `x1, x2 = np.hsplit(x,2)` will yield `x1.shape: (4, 1, 3)`. The unstacked dimension can be removed with `squeeze`: `x1, x2 = [ xx.squeeze() for xx in np.hsplit(x,2)]`, now  `x1.shape: (4, 3)`